# halting puppeteer process until a global var value changes from false to some string

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

im running puppeteer within my nodejs server ... idea is to open a page ,read and send captcha to a user via socket.io and when receive typed value captcha from user to proceed with the puppeteer ... here is simplified version of my code

```
   var captcha = false ;

    io.on('connection' , function(socket){

        socket.on('start_puppeteer' , function (data) {
            io.emit('push_msg' , {text : 'starting puppeteer  ....  '  });
            run(io);
        })

        socket.on('get_captcha_from_client' , function (data) {

            captcha = data.text ;
            console.log( 'capthca set : ' + captcha);
        })

    });

    function get_captcha() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve , reject ) {
            if(captcha === false )
                reject(captcha );
            else
                resolve(captcha);
        });
    }


async function run(io) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('http://localhost');

    console.log( ' sending captcha to client ' );

    io.emit('send_captcha_to_client' , {text : 'captcha text'  });

    var captcha = await get_captcha();

    console.log( ' captcha confirm -> ' + captcha );

    browser.close();
}
```

problem is even when captcha is set the code wouldnt move along and i dont get `captcha confirm` in the console

```
$ node pop.js
 sending captcha to client
(node:9356) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: false
(node:9356) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().
 (rejection id: 3)
(node:9356) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
capthca set : 1234
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanx to @Vaviloff and @yaniv-efraim i solved the probkem like this

```
var fullfillCaptcha;
var captchaPromise = new Promise(resolve => fullfillCaptcha = resolve);


    socket.on('get_captcha_from_client' , function (data) {

        fullfillCaptcha(data.text);
    })
```

and inside `async function run`

```
  var captcha = await captchaPromise;
```

Answer (score 1):

`page.waitForFunction` evaluates a function *[in browser context](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args)*, i.e. you can check for a certain DOM node presence or for a value of an input, but you only have access to the page objects inside of that function.

Now if you just want to wait for captcha to be solved, make your `get_captcha` return `Promise` and `await` for its result:

```
function get_captcha() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {

        // ...Do something lengthy here...

        resolve(captcha);
    });
}

async function run(io) {
    // ....

    await page.goto('http://localhost');
    io.emit('send_captcha_to_client' , {text : 'captcha text'  });
    var captcha = await get_captcha();

    // ....
}
```

Comment: thanx , im new to promises i searched around and did what i thought was right .... but i cant get pass promise ... ive updated my question and posted the whole code ... pleas take a look